# Undefined Constant WP_PLUGIN_URL

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins

I'm creating Wordpress plugin and I start to working with some js files. In order to use php in js file, I'm using php `header("Content-type: text/javascript")` and start to insert the rest of the javascript codes at bottom. When I tried to use WP_PLUGIN_URL, it tells me is not defined. How to define WP_PLUGIN_URL in this way ?

Myscript.js turns out to be myscript.php.

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: text/javascript");
$bigStarsPath =  WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/horoscope-plugin/js/icons/star.png';
$smallStarsPath = WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/horoscope-plugin/js/icons/small.png';
?>

/* JS Start Here*/
(function($) {
$.fn.jRating = function(op) {
var defaults = {
/** String vars **/
 bigStarsPath : '<?php echo $bigStarsPath; ?>', // path of the icon stars.png
 smallStarsPath : '<?php echo $smallStarsPath; ?>', // path of the icon small.png
 ...
```

**Plugin index page :**

```
function myscript() {
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
/*REGISTER ALL JS FOR SITE*/
wp_register_script('jRating', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/horoscope-plugin/js/jRating.jquery.php');

/*REGISTER ALL CSS FOR SITE*/;
wp_register_style('stylesheet',WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/horoscope-plugin/css/style.css');

/*CALL ALL CSS AND JS SCRIPT*/
wp_enqueue_style('stylesheet');
wp_enqueue_script('jRating');   
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','myscript');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this,

First add this code to your theme's `functions.php` file,

```
function mycustomjs_init()
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mycustomjs', "JS_FILE_PATH");

    $bigStarsPath =  WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/horoscope-plugin/js/icons/star.png';
    $smallStarsPath = WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/horoscope-plugin/js/icons/small.png';

    wp_localize_script( 'mycustomjs', 'bigStarsPath', array('url' => $bigStarsPath));
    wp_localize_script( 'mycustomjs', 'smallStarsPath', array('url' => $smallStarsPath));
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'mycustomjs_init' );
```

Replace `JS_FILE_PATH` with your js file path...

Now in your `js` file, use your defined variables like this `bigStarsPath.url` & `smallStarsPath.url`...

Hope it work...

Comment: It doesn't work for me, even in theme's functions or plugins. I want only works with plugin folder. Thanks You !

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
plugins_url()
```

Source::
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url